# Transform a POJO with HashMap?

Tags: java, pojo

Given a User POJO, use the `User` object as the key, the user's `username` as the value, and the HashMap to store it. When the `userId` is the same, it is considered that it can be the same object. The `User` class is as shown below.

```
public class User {
    private Long userId;
    private String username;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

How to transform the `User` class? And how to write the equals/hashCode methods?

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Do you know what methods need to be written to check for equality and get its hash key?

Comment: Why does the class need to be rewritten?  The question is just asking for you to use a User as the key in a hashmap ("given a User POJO...").  OK, you're going to have to add equals/hashCode methods to the User, but that is not what I would call 'rewriting' it.

Answer (score 2):

To compare two objects you can override the equals method in your class as follows

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;//same object
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;//something went wrong
        User tmp = (User) o;
     return this.getUserId() == tmp.getUserId();
    }
```

This way, when you store in your hashmap with a user instance as key, you can retrieve the tuple by using any other User instance with the same userId.

```
    User user1 = new User(new Long(1),"foouser");
    User user2 = new User(new Long(1),"foouserv3");

    map.put(user1,user1.getUsername());
    System.out.println(map.get(user2));
```

This prints "foouser",the value we have stored in the HashMap